# Cal-Heatmap - Display arbitrary past 30 days instead of full month

Tags: javascript, cal-heatmap

Is it possible to take a Cal-HeatMap and display the past 30 days in a month domain instead the date-range for that month?

Could custom domains be defined or is this functionality already available? I wasn't able to find anything on the documentation page on github.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it doesn't appear to be possible via the API. Unless you delve into the source and customize the month output yourself, there doesn't seem to be any other way.